# find selected item in custom paging

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wrote custom paging to a repeater. Here below is code. When I clicked a LinkButton, How to set selected it or how to set css class?

Firstly I tried to set css class in lbl_Click function like this `lnk.CssClass = "classname";`  On every attempt, It sets css class all clicked linkbutton.

```
private void CreatePagingControl()
    {                           
         for (int i = 0; i < pages; i++)
         {
            LinkButton lnk = new LinkButton();
            lnk.Click += new EventHandler(lbl_Click);
            lnk.ID = "lnkPage" + (i + 1).ToString();
            lnk.Text = (i + 1).ToString();
            plcPaging.Controls.Add(lnk);
            Label spacer = new Label();
            spacer.Text = "&nbsp;|&nbsp;";
            plcPaging.Controls.Add(spacer);
         }            
    }

    void lbl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton lnk = sender as LinkButton;
        int currentPage = int.Parse(lnk.Text);
        int take = currentPage * 15;
        int skip = currentPage == 1 ? 0 : take - 15;
        FetchData(take, skip);
    }
```

aspx

```
   <asp:PlaceHolder ID="plcPaging" runat="server" />
```

Comment: @jbl; yeap, I setted `lnk.CssClass = "classname";`

Comment: Your skip/take logic is flawed.  You should take 15 every time and skip `(currentPage-1)*15`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Change you aspx to this

```
<div id="pageingDiv">
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="plcPaging" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField id="currentId" runatserver" value="1" />
</div>
```

Call this Jquery script to `$(document).ready()`

```
$("#pageingDiv a").removeClass();
var hvId = $('[id$=currentId]').val();
$("#lnkPage" _ hvId).AddClass('ClassName');
```

Then in your codebehind add css

```
void lbl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
LinkButton lnk = sender as LinkButton;
int currentPage = int.Parse(lnk.Text);
int take = currentPage * 15;
int skip = currentPage == 1 ? 0 : take - 15;
FetchData(take, skip);
//add css here
currentId.Value=currentPage.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this, which should also work when CssClass contains more than one class.

```
// removing a cssClass
protected String removeCssClass(string cssClass, string toRemove)
{
    return String.Join(" ", cssClass.Split(' ').Except(new[] {toRemove}).ToArray());
}

void lbl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // resetting all selected items
    plcPaging.Controls
      .OfType<Label>()
      .Where(l => l.ID.StartsWith("lnkPage") && l.CssClass.Split(' ').Contains("selectedClassName")).ToList()
      .ForEach(l => l.CssClass = removeCssClass(l.CssClass, "classname"));
    LinkButton lnk = sender as LinkButton;
    // setting selected item
    lnk.CssClass = "classname";
    int currentPage = int.Parse(lnk.Text);
    int take = currentPage * 15;
    int skip = currentPage == 1 ? 0 : take - 15;
    FetchData(take, skip);
}
```

Hope this will help